# NSmutable Dictionary with MultipleKeys to Store in SingleArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am doing a small concept on NSMutableDictionary.
I have four keys (Name, Age, PhoneNumber, Gender) for 10 employees.

**How can I assign these values to an array?**

Individually I passed 4 different values for the dictionary but the fourth value is coming repeatedly.
this is the code what i have written
- (void)viewDidLoad {

```
NSLog(@"in mytableviews viewdidload");



  EmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];





//namesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"jam",@"jack",@"gillchrist",@"jackson"];


  EmpDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [EmpDictionary setValue:@"martin" forKey:@"name"];
 [EmpDictionary setValue:@"18" forKey:@"age"];
 [EmpDictionary setValue:@"M" forKey:@"gender"];
 [EmpDictionary setValue:@"9652893070" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [EmpArray addObject:EmpDictionary];
NSLog(@"emparray counr %d",[self.EmpArray count]);



[EmpDictionary setValue:@"jack" forKey:@"name"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"19" forKey:@"age"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"F" forKey:@"gender"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"96656893070" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
[EmpArray addObject:EmpDictionary];

[EmpDictionary setValue:@"Louis" forKey:@"name"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"21" forKey:@"age"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"F" forKey:@"gender"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"9652893060" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
[EmpArray addObject:EmpDictionary];

[EmpDictionary setValue:@"Gillchrist" forKey:@"name"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"23" forKey:@"age"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"M" forKey:@"gender"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:@"99998989" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
 [EmpArray addObject:EmpDictionary];


 [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

```
NSLog(@"creating cell in cell for row at index"); 

employeeCell *empcell = (employeeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"empcell1"];

if(empcell==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"In creating cell");
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"employeeCell" owner:self options:nil];
    empcell=tableCell;
}

for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
{

    NSLog(@"after creating cell");

    //NSDictionary *temp=[self.EmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *temp = [self.EmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *empname= [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *age= [temp objectForKey:@"age"];
//NSInteger age = [temp objectForKey:@"age"];
NSString *gender= [temp objectForKey:@"gender"];
NSString  *phonenumber = [temp objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];

empcell.EmpName.text=empname;

empcell.EmpAge.text=age;

 empcell.EmpGender.text=gender;
empcell.EmpPhoneNumber.text=phonenumber;


empcell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
return empcell;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean with coming repeatedly? So you want an array of dictionaries?

Comment: thank you Olli for modifying the question.please give suggestion for it .thank u once again

Comment: i mean repeatedly means in table view for every cell i am getting same vaule's(Smith,1244,london,05897469878).these are the last values for dictionary i have passed in the coding .please help regarding it .thanku for giving respose for my question.

Comment: Can you post any code? It will give me more idea of what your doing and maybe i can see where it is going wrong.

Comment: this is code what i have written in view did load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to either create new dictionaries for each set of entries you want to add *or* do

```
[[EmpArray addObject:[EmpDictionary copy]];
```

Otherwise, you're just adding the same object 4 times, so your end result show 4 cells with the same information in them. Your end array is not 4 different objects, just 4 pointers to the same object.